# How to re-fork a branch in Git after deleting it

Tags: git, github

I forked an `original_repo` to `my_repo`, it had two branches `origin/master` and `origin/dev`. I cloned `my_repo` to my PC and added `original_repo` as a remote upstream. I worked on `dev` branch locally and commited it, pushed it to `my_repo`. Then submitted a PR and when it was accepted, Git suggested that I delete the branch `dev`. I did that and `my_repo` no longer have `dev` branch. From PC, I deleted the `dev` using `git branch -d dev` command.

1. But why does it still show `dev` branch in this command? Isn't this like tracking but since `dev` is no more in `my_repo` why are they still here?

   ```
   c:\> git branch -a
   * master
     remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
     remotes/origin/dev
     remotes/origin/master
     remotes/upstream/dev
     remotes/upstream/master
   ```
2. After deleting `dev` branch it disappeared from `my_repo` as expected, but how do I fork it again from `original_repo` as I've to work on another bug? I feel like I can delete `my_repo` and local PC clone and fork `original_repo` again. Or is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete the branch in the upstream repo, it does not delete the tracking branches in the local repo.  When you delete your local branch with the same name, it *still* does not delete the tracking branch for the remote repo.

The easiest way to "clean up" is to use `git fetch -p` (or `--prune`), which will clean up (and delete) local tracking branches for remote branches that have been deleted.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea how to solve my second question?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting is local does't delete your remote copy. You need to delete the branch in local and in Remote. 
To remove Remote Branch you need to Run

> git push origin --delete dev

this makes to delete remote Branch.

Flow this Blog to understand More

[How can I delete branches in Git](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/delete-remote-branch)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea how to solve my second question?